# What determines how much RAM a program uses?

Tags: memory

Using games as an example - I could be playing a game which takes up 30GB of storage on my HDD, but the game could be only using 2GB of memory. Obviously the game isn't loaded all at once, but is the RAM usage equal to how much data is being read + used from the HDD?

tl;dr Why does a game using 2GB memory actually use 2GB memory, what is the deciding factor?

Comment: Let's assume I have 3 GB game (hard drive requirement) but a 2GB RAM required. 
Let's assume there are 2 x 0.5GB pictures, 2 x 0.5GB sounds and 1 x GB code. At any point, it's likely I will need 1 graphic (0.5GB), 1 sound (0.5GB) and the code (1GB). Add them up, and you have 2 GB! Obviously, if the graphics department made each graphic 1GB in size, then my overall game hard drive requirement and RAM usage increases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"is the RAM usage equal to how much data is being read + used from the HDD?" No, it is not that simple. Today's operating systems all use virtual memory. The RAM the program uses will almost always be a subset of the total virtual address space the program defines, for two reasons.

First, because the program will almost never access all of the v.a.s. it defines. For example, suppose you never explore a particular corridor on a game level - there's no reason to bring that data in from disk. Or if you don't happen to use the numbered list feature in Word, there's no reason to bring in that code. Code and data is generally "demand paged", meaning it is only paged in if it's actually referenced ("demanded") by the program.

Second, even after stuff has been paged in, the operating system may decide that something else can make better use of some of the RAM and page some of it out - particularly if it hasn't been referenced for a while, and especially on systems with small amounts of RAM for their workload (called "RAM pressure"). This too can apply to both code and data separately. A naive example would be the data for a level you haven't been to for a while.

The result of the above is that the amount of RAM a program "uses" is really better thought of as the amount of virtual address space the program has referenced recently, limited further by what the OS allows the program to use. It can vary  widely depending on how much RAM you have, what else is running on the system, and what the program is doing.

tl;dr: It's complicated. The "memory management" chapter of *Windows Internals*, 6th. ed., is about 200 pages, which is a fair-sized book all by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was hoping it would be a little more simple but I'm always up for some extra reading - i'll take a look at Windows Internals, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Several factors actually.

1. Max allowed - Operating system has very complicated and delicate mechanisms governing RAM usage. Those include limits on how much RAM any given application uses. for example Windows limit depends on version (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx)
2. What program is actually doing. For example Microsof Office will use less memory than newest FPP simply because it must hold much less data for rendering and calculations.
3. What type the program is - as previously: game uses a lot of RAM because it must store there graphics data of all kinds (rendering, effects, calculations etc). Also, quality of display is a huge factor.
4. Actual hardware - if system has large RAM for graphics (on graphics adapter) then it will use it first, then only resort to ram to hold actual application files and currently processed data. If it has not enough, it will resort to use a lot of RAM right to the limit.
5. Actual folder size of the game is primarily rendering and other game data - walls, landscape, terrain, weapons characteristics, sound effects etc. is all previously described. Think of it as it would be a wireframe of sorts. When you play computer "only" fills that data with textures and so on - actual walls. The higher quality you choose, the more processing power and memory system will use and if it will not be enough, it will be slooooow. And this is actually also the reason why each stage/mission/chapter is loaded separately - because there is no space available for it all at once.

EDIT: added another link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - It seems a lot more complicated than I first thought!